# Replace malformed special characters with their actual character in MSSQL 2019 database

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have a database in which I inserted hundreds of thousands of city values over the years.
See this other post of mine for some context: [Storing special characters (German, French, Spanish) in SQL Server result in weird strings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312885/storing-special-characters-german-french-spanish-in-sql-server-result-in-wei).
My database collation is as of now still `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

While new values are added correctly, I'm now stuck with all sorts of historically incorrectly inserted values in my database.

Below are the values I see vs what I want:

```
Value in my database        Actual desired value
KrakĂłw                     Kraków
Strzelce KrajeĹskie        Strzelce Krajeńskie
SÄpĂłlno KrajeĹskie       Sępólno Krajeńskie
```

Adding an image too since the characters from my database are not coming through here on StackOverflow:

[image]

Two questions:

1. Are my wrong values above indeed ascii special characters like I suspect?  ([I also checked here already](https://www.sqlshack.com/replace-ascii-special-characters-sql-server/))
2. What would be the command to do a find/replace so that I can replace the `ĹIND` part of the existing value with `ń`? e.g. `REPLACE(name,'Ä','ó')`

Comment: Do you need to store characters that aren’t in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS?  If so you’ll need to use an NVARCHAR or UTF-8 VARCHAR comumn.  And there’s no automated way to fix your data.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks! I started using `NVARCHAR` for my columns recently, so I guess I'm safe with my existing collation for newly inserted values? And your 2nd answer scares me! Why exactly would a `REPLACE` statement like in my example bullet 2 NOT work? Is that because there's no way to recognize the string "ÄSGCI"?

Comment: It's because there's not a 1-1 mapping between Unicode characters and SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS characters.  So sure, you can replace `N'Ä'`, with `N'ó'`, but there may be other source characters that got mapped to `N'Ä'`.  And remember to use unicode literals `REPLACE(name,N'Ä',N'ó')`.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case....oh boy am I scr**ed then. Thanks for your answer though, please add as an answer so I can mark this as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store characters that aren’t in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS you’ll need to use an NVARCHAR or UTF-8 VARCHAR column. And there’s no 100% automated way to fix your data because there's not a 1-1 mapping between Unicode characters and SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS characters. So sure, you can replace `N'Ä'`, with `N'ó'`, but there may be other source characters that got mapped to `N'Ä'` or `N'Ä'` may legitimately appear in your data.

And remember to use always use Unicode literals `REPLACE(name,N'Ä',N'ó')`. Or else your literal 'ó' will be converted to a single-byte character in the database's collation.

It's just work; you'll just have to verify that that replacement isn't going to break other values before doing a global replace, and for some values you may need change them row-by-row.